# how to make navigation between pages in xamarin.ios?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin

i used below code which caused  an error that no overload for method  InstantiateInitialViewController takes '1' argument

```
EfficientBilling365ViewController  abc=this.Storyboard.InstantiateInitialCiewController(EbViewController) as EfficientBillingViewController;
if(abc!=null)
{
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(abc,true);
}
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5):

First of all from AppDelegate.cs you create your viewcontroller and then you encapsulate it into a NavigationController like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
MyViewController myViewController = new MyViewController ();
UINavigationController navContr = new UINavigationController (myViewController);
window.RootViewController = navContr;
//Other things
}
```

After that your myViewController is the first page and when you do something you will go into the new page so in `myViewContoller` you will do something like this:

```
NavigationController.PushViewController (newViewController, true);
```

Hope this helps, storyboards is not needed and I find this the easiest way to navigate between pages.

Comment: @Hustler did it help? Do you need something else?

Comment: It seems this user is only interested in getting quick answers. He doesn't care for the one answering. +1 from me. See all his previous questions, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28040118/993547.

Answer (score 3):

i think this is the solution !!

```
UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

var contentController =(product_co)AppDelegate.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("product_co");

this.NavigationController.PushViewController(contentController, true);
```

Comment: And what makes you think that?