# "Cannot add the libraries to incompatible component" when adding JSON.NET to Xamarin project

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I got this error while adding JSON.NET component into my Xamarin iOS app.

The error message is:

> error adding to project: cannot add the libraries to incompatible component

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Xamarin doesn't support the full .NET framework, there is a slimmed down version of JSON.NET that is a specific PCL ([Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), also [here on the Xamarin site](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/)) written for Xamarin.

See [the Xamarin components site](https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/) for the JSON.NET version for Xamarin.

Comment: ok bro. i want to read php json as object in ios project. how to do it?

Comment: That is a totally different question, and it requires some research from your side first. Give it a try, look for documentation on the pages linked, and you will be fine. If you have any questions left then, ask a new question. Add a clear problem statement, relevant code and JSON there.

Comment: using below code , i read as json array. but i want to split it as separate object.   string username = "john";
string urlAddress = "http://www.yoursite.tld/somepage.php?username=" + username;  
 
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
       // this string contains the webpage's source
       string pagesource = client.DownloadString(urlAddress);  
}

Comment: if i add json.net componet into my project, i can read json as object .

Comment: but xamarin mentioned as Json.NET is compatible with both android and ios

Comment: It is, but you need a specific version.

Comment: For help with code, ask a new question please. Or search the JSON documentation, it is very useful.

Comment: @Hustler: Did this answer your question? If so, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked best.

Comment: Do Not Disturb for a old question

Comment: @Hustler: Sorry, did I miss anything? I was trying to help you and you tell me not to disturb you?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason you are getting the "cannot add the libraries to incompatible component" is because you have an old version of Xamarin Studio installed.

The latest Json.NET component from Xamarin's Component Store is a shell component and only installs the Json.NET NuGet package. If you have an old version of Xamarin Studio you will not be able to install Json.NET from the Component store. You need at least Xamarin Studio 5.5 to install Json.NET from the Component store.

Another alternative is to install the Json.NET NuGet package instead of the component from the Component store. You can do that by selecting your project, right clicking and selecting Add - Add Packages.

Comment: ok. i had tried.but there is no option as u mentioned Add-Add Package

Comment: Or with your project selected in the Solution window, open the main Project menu and use Add Packages... or Add NuGet Packages. What version of Xamarin Studio do you have installed?

Comment: ok matt ward...already you solved my problem by answer at xamarin forums. thans a lot